# Составить регулярное выражение для строкового образца

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Только начал осваивать регулярные выражение и не могу разобраться. 
Есть такие строки:

```
Israel Weapon Industries

Rafael Advanced Defense Systems

Israel Aerospace Industries

Israel Military Industries
```

То есть, регулярное выражение должно удовлетворять такие условия:

1) Строка состоит из одного или нескольких слов, каждое начинается с большой буквы.

2) Строка состоит только из букв.

Помогите составить регулярное выражение. Не могу понять, как это сделать. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Первое что-то типа $[A-Z][a-z]+(\s [A-Z][a-z]+)*?^. Если разберёшься с этим то 2 просто будет составить;)

Comment: Желательно уточнить, регулярки какого именно языка/платформы нужно использовать. Потому что в разных реализациях есть разные возможности.